# Play Scala: class needs to be abstract

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm beginner on Play in Scala and I receive this error when I want to open my app:

```
class ElevesController needs to be abstract, since method messagesApi in trait I18nSupport of type => play.api.i18n.MessagesApi is not defined
```

EleveController.scala

```
package controllers

import javax.inject.Inject
import play.api.Logger
import play.api.data.Form
import play.api.data.Forms._
import play.api.i18n.{Messages, I18nSupport, MessagesApi}
import play.api.mvc.{Action, Controller}
import views.html
import scala.concurrent.Future
import models.Eleve

class ElevesController @Inject() extends Controller with I18nSupport {


  def viewEleves = Action {implicit request =>
    Ok(html.viewseleves(Eleve.findAll))
  }
}
```

I dont know how to fix it

Edit: 
I fix it, I just need to add: "(val messagesApi: MessagesApi)" in this line:

```
    class ElevesController @Inject()(val messagesApi: MessagesApi) extends Controller with I18nSupport {
```

Comment: huh, for some reason we'd been using `@Inject()(messagesApi: MessagesApi)` without the `val` which compiles and everything until you need mixins!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work. Just change your action etc.

https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.0-RC2/api/scala/index.html#play.api.i18n.I18nSupport

```
               package controllers

               import javax.inject._
               import play.api._


                import javax.inject.Inject
                import play.api.Logger
                import play.api.data.Form
                import play.api.data.Forms._
                import play.api.mvc._
                import views.html
                import scala.concurrent.Future
                import play.api.i18n._

                  @Inject() 
                class ElevesController (val messagesApi: MessagesApi)  extends Controller   with I18nSupport {

                   val action = Action { implicit request =>
                    Ok("Ok") // Uses the client???s preferred language
                       }

                    }
```